# unordered_set: is pointer address a good hash?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

i want to store a set of (smart) pointers in a hash set, either `<boost/unordered_set>`. After 10 seconds of thought, i came up with this hash function:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<myType> ref_t;
struct SharedPtrHash : public std::unary_function<ref_t, std::size_t> {                        
    std::size_t operator()(ref_t const& obj) const {
      return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>( obj.get() );
    }
};
```

My question is: is this hash a good idea? i'm entertaining the thought that this hash will have zero or very few collisions (maybe there is some prime-number modulus under the hood spoiling all my fun).

**Further Details on purpose:** The purpose of the hash is for recycling storage of big objects, so i need a fast way to detect if a big object is already in the bin.

in case it is not, what would be an ideal hash for pointers, either smart or dumb ones?

Comment: Well, memory addresses should be unique so I'd (after 5 seconds of thought) would say you're good to go.

Comment: myType will probably have a minimum alignment, which may be as high as 8.  Which means all results will be divisible by 8.  Not the greatest hash, especially since there probably is a modulo by power of two.

Comment: If you want to look up using object identity on your keys it's a good hash. If you want object equality it's a bug.

Comment: great point @Mooing Duck. Any suggestions for a screaming fast hash in here?

Comment: @Patrick, i know, this is for recycling storage of big objects, so identity is what matters. But Mooing Duck made a great point about address having low entropy due to alignment

Comment: Why would you feel the need to implement this yourself? Have you checked whether smart pointers aren't already supported?

Comment: `obj.get()>>alignof(myType)`   :(  I'm not good at hashing

Comment: MarkRansom points out dividing by `sizeof(myType)` would be better

Comment: For a really fast hash, just keep a global counter. Each time you create a new object increment the counter and use the new value as the hash.

Comment: @DavidGiven Hash functions are supposed to yield the same result every time you call them with an object with the same value. If you're just returning the value of a counter, the hash code will always change, even if the value of the object is the same. Maybe I misunderstood, but that doesn't sound like a hash function at all.

Comment: To clarify: when each object is created, it remembers the value of the counter at that time, and when asked for its hash it returns that value. It's a cheap way of ensuring that every object returns a different hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect objects that are *not* identical even though their contents might be equal, you have *no choice* but to use the address of the object in the hash. The only question is whether to use the address directly or to run it through a formula. Dividing by `sizeof(mytype)` would tighten up the holes in the distribution.

**Edit:** Here's an untested template implementation that should work with all `shared_ptr` types, along with an `equal_to` function to complete the requirements for `std::unordered_set`. Don't use this generic implementation if you have other objects that require a hash based on the value instead of the pointer.

```
template<typename T>
size_t hash(const std::shared_ptr<T> & ptr)
{
    return ((size_t) ptr.get()) / sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T>
bool equal_to(const std::shared_ptr<T> & left, const std::shared_ptr<T> & right)
{
    return left.get() == right.get();
}
```

Comment: oh, that's way better than dividing by alignment.

Comment: How exactly is dividing by the size a good idea? If you have a mix of small and large adjacent objects, you'll create lots of collisions. The pointer will typically align only to the largest member's alignment (recursively), non?

Comment: @Kerrek, in this case, the hash is type-specific, similar to flyweight but without the value semantics. So, there is no mix of small and large objects happening (in the same hash)

Comment: I see - if you only do this for one concrete type, rather than as a partial specialization for all shared pointers, then that might indeed work. I have no idea if it makes any difference in terms of hash collisions, but it certainly makes sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB, if there are different objects you can just divide by the size of the smallest. That will still guarantee unique hashes for each one.

Comment: I don't see why you *should* divide by anything at all. Hash values in STL are always size_t, and the size of a pointer is also (I think?) guaranteed to be size_t...

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, it's all about getting good collision performance in the hash buckets. I haven't dug into this deep enough to know for sure, but intuitively a hash formula that doesn't have holes in the distribution will perform better than one that does.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't agree with you there. If you don't have holes, and the way the hash table works is simply by enumerating (e.g. `while (collision) { ++index; }`) you will get a ton of collisions the moment you hit a collision. I've seen this happens in lots of hash table implementations. The same holds for values that are usually used as period of the hash (such as powers of 2). Intentionally adding lots of holes (I usually multiply by a pretty large prime) fixes both these issues.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Since all pointers to a same type have a same alignment, means that all pointers will have a value that is a multiplier of a same value. For example, if the pointer type is `T*` and alignment of `T` is `8`, only buckets 0, 8, 16, etc... will have values. So you are basically only using a 1/alignment(T) percent of buckets available and the numbers of collisions will be huge.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles perfectly (GCC 4.7, Boost 1.47):

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct Foo { };

int main()
{
  boost::unordered_set<boost::shared_ptr<int>> s;
  boost::shared_ptr<int> pi(new int);
  s.insert(pi);

  boost::unordered_set<boost::shared_ptr<Foo>> t;
  boost::shared_ptr<Foo> pf(new Foo);
  t.insert(pf);
}
```

Comment: yes, shared_ptr is using by default the implementation above, i'm just concerned about how good is this hash

Comment: So.... that's the same thing you're proposing in your question. I'm saying that exactly that is already implemented by default. And yes, it'll be good.

Comment: ok, what are your thoughts on the alignment issue? wouldn't it be better if the address is divided by sizeof(T)?

Comment: @lurscher: The people who wrote the hash for shared_ptr are the same guys who figured out how to make a shared_ptr.  Give them a little credit.  It's going to be a good enough hash :D

Comment: in fact, it its good enough for most cases, but the improvement suggested by Mark makes it a little bit tighter at little extra cost

Answer (score 0):

The default `Boost.Hash` `hash` function for integral types is the identity function, so I don't think doing the same for pointers is a bad idea. It would have the same collision ratio.

Comment: alignment might hose you though